# Quais as diferenças entre BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY e BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY?

Tags: c, compilação

Ao tentar compilar, me deparei com essas duas opções, no meu caso apenas uma deu certo, o que me levou as perguntas:

- O que um poderia ter, que o outro não tem?
- Qual vantagem, e desvantagem em usar `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` ou `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY`?
- Existem outros como esses?

Answer (score 1):

**`BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY`**: Esta variável aponta para um script de construção que recolhe todas as informações sobre o módulo que você forneceu em suas variáveis ​​de `LOCAL_XXX`, e determina como construir uma biblioteca compartilhada de destino a partir das fontes que você listou. Usar este script requer que você já atribuiu valores a `LOCAL_MODULE` and `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

**`BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY`**: É usada para construir uma biblioteca estática. O sistema de construção não copia bibliotecas estáticas em seu `project/packages`, mas pode usá-los para construir bibliotecas compartilhadas.

Nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149376/51124), explica a diferença, vantagens e desvantagens da linkagem estática e dinâmica.

Para saber mais sobre `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` e `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` a própria [documentação](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html) te explica e sugere links para que você possa entender melhor o funcionamento delas.