# Qual a diferença entre linkagem estática e dinâmica?

Tags: c, c++, compilação, golang

Recentemente, pesquisando o porque de códigos pequenos em Go possuírem um executável muito maior do que o mesmo código gerado em C, [eu li uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3861677/694105) afirmando que o motivo é por conta do Go utilizar ***linkagem* estática**, ao contrário do C, que usa ***linkagem* dinâmica**.

O que exatamente esses termos significam? Existe algum tipo de vantagem e/ou desvantagem entre as duas alternativas além do tamanho final do executável?

Comment: Relacionado a [Qual a diferença de DLL e lib?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44269/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-dll-e-lib)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Isso foi uma simplificação da resposta, C pode usar as duas formas. Em tese Go poderia também, não sei se o [*linker*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101) da linguagem é capaz hoje. A não ser que tenha algo na especificação da linguagem que impeça a *linkagem* dinâmica (que eu saiba não tem), nada impede que venha a ter se não quebrar compatibilidade.

A **estática** é criar um executável monolítico, assim tudo o que você precisa já está ali no executável.

A **dinâmica** permite que partes sejam geradas separadamente e adicionadas ao executável posteriormente (durante a execução). Essas partes precisam ter uma forma de se comunicar, um protocolo básico, mas não precisam ter conhecimento dos detalhes do que está em cada parte. Cada parte é *linkada* em separado. Pode ser até que sejam de fornecedores diferentes que apenas ofereçam uma API de acesso ao executável para carregamento dinâmico (a tal forma de se comunicar).

## Vantagens e desvantagens da dinâmica

Várias técnicas podem ser usadas para isso mas o mais comum é ter as DLLs (Dynamic-Link Library) ou SOs (Shared Object) que são executáveis preparados justamente para serem carregados em conjunto com outro executável principal.

No passado o tamanho do executável e o reaproveitamento de partes que podem ser usadas para várias aplicações eram vantagens muito desejadas. Hoje isso tem menos importância e a capacidade de substituir partes de forma independente passou ser a principal vantagem da *linkagem* dinâmica.

Note que se fizer um executável e várias DLLs, o tamanho total do executável fica maior, não só em disco (para transmitir em rede), mas também em memória. Não é muito, mas é maior. Só compensaria se o computador já possui boa parte dessas DLLs.

Há casos que a *linkagem* dinâmica é necessária por causa da licença (LGPL por exemplo).

## Vantagem e desvantagens da estática

Particularmente eu prefiro a estática até onde dá. Fica mais fácil gerenciar e instalar, tem mais performance de carga (ainda que mínima) e permite melhores otimizações (poder analisar tudo é muito poderoso).

Mas é menos flexível, não permite esse sistema de *plugin* (quase sempre não preciso dessa flexibilidade, menos ainda preciso reaproveitar partes do executável).

Também evita algumas indireções e outras técnicas desnecessárias em muitos casos. Um exemplo é [criar *getters* e *setters* porque algo pode ser carregado dinamicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101). Em *linkagem* estática garantida essa técnica não ajuda muito.

Alguns dirão que não carrega todo o executável se for dinâmica, mas isso ocorre com a estática também. O sistema operacional é inteligente e carrega só as páginas necessárias. Isso não é uma desvantagem da estática.

## Conclusão

Pode ler mais sobre o assunto em [Qual a diferença de DLL e lib?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44269/101). E também [Diferença de desempenho entre biblioteca estática e compartilhada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123049/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

Linkagem estática significa que as bibliotecas necessárias ao funcionamento do programa são embutidas no próprio arquivo do executável. Quem faz isso é o linker, daí o nome.

Na linkagem dinâmica as bibliotecas permanecem fora do executável, e são carregadas "dinamicamente", no momento da execução.

Uma desvantagem da linkagem estática você já descobriu: o tamanho do executável aumenta. Outras desvantagens:

- se uma biblioteca tiver problemas, como por exemplo precisar de uma atualização de segurança como é tão comum hoje em dia, não basta atualizar a biblioteca, é preciso atualizar todos os programas que linkaram estaticamente essa biblioteca;
- o programa ocupa mais espaço em memória porque, se diversos programas linkaram estaticamente a mesma biblioteca, eles não podem compartilhar as páginas de memória desse biblioteca, enquanto isso é possível na linkagem dinâmica.

Agora as vantagens:

- Uma atualização da biblioteca que dê errado não afeta o programa. Isto evita o "DLL hell" do Windows, onde diferentes programas dependem de diferentes versões do mesmo DLL para funcionar direito.
- É mais fácil instalar (deploy) o programa em produção porque há menos dependências, ou mesmo nenhuma dependência;
- Há uma pequena vantagem de velocidade (2% a 3%) num programa linkado estaticamente, porque os endereços das funções das bibliotecas são resolvidos pelo linker.

Há uma certa tendência de crescimento da linkagem estática; por exemplo, programas em Go e Rust linkam estaticamente. Hoje em dia o tamanho dos executáveis é relativamente pequeno perto dos ativos (imagens, sons, videos), e já se criou a cultura de atualização periódica dos programas.

No MacOS a abordagem é híbrida: o aplicativo é uma pasta e todas as bibliotecas dinâmicas necessárias ficam lá dentro, o que também evita o "DLL hell".