# O que são símbolos no .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, debug

Como funcionam os símbolos no .NET Framework (e em outras plataformas)? Como eles tornam possível efetuar o *debug* remoto de uma aplicação mesmo sem ter o código fonte na máquina? Qual a sua relação com os arquivos `.pdb`?

Comment: Caso você entenda inglês, pode ser que ajude: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/05/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studios-symbol-settings/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Símbolos

Símbolos são nomes. De fato isso serve para qualquer aplicação, não é exclusivo do .NET. Eles estão vinculados à algum endereço, mas não necessariamente um endereço físico ou fixo, ele pode ser um indicador relativo de uma posição relativa na pilha que será absoluta só no momento da execução. Símbolos são identificadores do código (variáveis, nomes de funções, etc.), mas o chamamos assim quando tratamos de um nível um pouco mais baixo. Apesar de haver uma relação 1:1 entre os identificadores e os símbolos só consideramos os símbolos os que sobrevivem à compilação.

Normalmente tudo o que é público precisa de um símbolo para mapear o objeto (num sentido amplo da palavra). Então funções, tipos, variáveis globais precisam ter seus símbolos disponíveis sempre para que outros componentes se referenciem a eles sem saber seu endereço. Isto é necessário especialmente em [*linkagem* dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149372/101). Em tese uma *linkagem estática* poderia eliminar todos os símbolos, pelo menos na maioria das situações.

O que é privado ou local não precisa disponibilizar esses símbolos porque o código consegue resolver tudo ali mesmo. Mas para depurar você precisa de um mapeamento do código binário para o fonte. É aí que entra as informações adicionais inseridas no executável ou em um arquivo separado.

## Arquivo de símbolos

Um arquivo de símbolos normalmente possui bem mais informações além dos símbolos. Só o mapeamento puro seria mais facilmente colocado dentro do executável, ou seja bastaria manter todos símbolos em uma tabela, não apenas os necessários para uso normal. Ele possui dados dos membros públicos além do seu nome que facilitam a depuração.

É possível ter até o código fonte nesse arquivo. Se não, pelo menos tem como mapear os binário ao fonte que esteja disponível na máquina. Assim sabe-se qual trecho de código fonte gerou uma determinada instrução da máquina e assim permite controlar a execução de forma simples.

Obviamente que se quiser depurar direto no código alvo não precisa de símbolos. Só que fica bem difícil. Hacker de verdade faz muito isso.

O arquivo pode conter informações de como apresentar dados de certos tipos para ser melhor visualizado.

Em geral pode configurar o nível de detalhe de informações que estará disponível.

## Arquivo PDB

A Microsoft usa o formato `.pdb` para guardar essas informações.

O termo é usado em alguns contextos do código:

- [Symbol table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table)
- [Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming))
- [Debug symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) (o mais adequado para esta pergunta)

[Maiores detalhes podem ser obtidos na MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/debugging-with-symbols?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Sobre o PDB:

- [Artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database)
- [Especificação](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb)
- [Artigo interessante](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know)

Veja o comentário do Artur na pergunta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).