# O que é uma tabela de símbolos?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, runtime, compiladores

Para que usamos uma tabela de símbolos? Em quais linguagens fazem sentido isso? Ela pode ser considerada uma estrutura de dados? Há diferença entre o uso em compiladores e executáveis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em termos gerais é uma estrutura de dados que contém os nomes das variáveis e outros nomes que a aplicação precisa, com sua localização na memória e outros metadados necessários para a execução ou depuração da aplicação.

Símbolos são apenas nomes para os metadados necessários, que pode ser só o endereço onde o objeto está. Então a estrutura tende a ser algo muito parecido com um dicionário/*hash* ou árvore. Além de variáveis, costumam ser funções, até com seu sobrenome, se tiver.

Ela pode existir de forma até mais completa durante o processo de compilação conforme vai avaliando o código fonte e montando a tabela de tudo o que foi declarado no código. Pode existir a tabela até mesmo em uma interpretação que muitas vezes não deixa de ser uma compilação e execução.

Existem compiladores que podem trabalhar sem uma tabela de símbolos, mas só para algumas linguagens que possuem uma estrutura simplificada. Eu sei que Go não usava uma, o que permitia uma compilação mais rápida, mas não sei se até hoje está assim, tem um ponto que se torna inevitável. Tem casos que ter uma pode otimizar a compilação.

Em alguns casos os dados são simplificados e alguns símbolos podem deixar de existir, por exemplo variáveis locais em algumas tecnologias (em geral as compiladas que geram um executável nativo ou não), e claro se não está depurando.

Em geral um executável contém uma tabela de símbolos globais, especialmente se eles puderem ser relocados, assim a tabela serve de indireção para determinar onde efetivamente esteja o objeto referenciado pelo símbolo. Nestes casos uma tabela é fornecida no executável (geralmente criada pelo *linker*) com um endereço base dentro da aplicação (*placeholder*) e quando o sistema operacional faz a carga ele identifica em que posição da memória efetivamente aquele objeto está presente para colocar na tabela e assim toda vez que for acessar o objeto ele sabe o local da memória por essa tabela.

Note que é necessário para objetos estáticos que o código referencia diretamente.

Linguagens que rodam em máquina virtual costumam ter uma tabela de símbolos para execução do código, muitas vezes de forma mais rica. Mais ainda para poder *debugar*. Algumas linguagens até podem manipular essa tabela, especialmente as [homoicônicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575855/101) e é comum chamar os símbolos de [*atoms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)#Atoms).

[Exemplo em .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204719/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).