# Um executável em linguagem de programação imperativa é menor do que um executável em linguagem orientada a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, otimização, independente-de-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação, programação-imperativa

Pois bem, é isso, geralmente programas orientados a objetos possuem diversas diversas chamadas a pequenos métodos para passagem de mensagens, o encapsulamento também é uma consequência comum do modelo, sem falar de polimorfismo e outras particularidades.

Então, sei que isso é bem relativo a compiladores e ao programa em si, bem como plataforma, no entanto, em uma estratégia geral de geração de código nativo, o executável de programas orientados a objeto é maior? Se sim, ou não, poderiam listar por quê (em relação a programas feitos em linguagem imperativa - como C)?

Estou estudando linguagens de programação, seus paradigmas e processos de compilação, seja qual for a etapa, então, podem ir bem baixo nível, tipo decisões de projeto em nível de compilador e arquitetura, de preferência ARMv7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não existe essa relação direta entre [paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) e tamanho de executável, principalmente de forma absoluta. E confunde duas coisas diferentes também sem relação, afinal o imperativo certamente é um paradigma, e orientação a objeto talvez não seja, pelo menos algumas não consideram assim, mas se for é um paradigma secundário, tanto que ele é usado junto com outro paradigma, quase sempre o imperativo. Entenda que existe o algoritmo que costuma ser imperativo (existem algumas linguagens que seguem o funcional, puro quase nenhuma, e bem raro outro paradigma) e organização geral do que se escreve e monta as estruturas de dados e onde estarão os algoritmos, o que representa no máximo um paradigma secundário, se for paradigma.

Não foi citado um exemplo de linguagem dita orientada a objeto, mas é quase certa que ela é imperativa na maioria parte do que você faz, então não há essa dicotomia. Vou considerar que está falando do uso procedural que também seria um paradigma secundário de organização de código e não como escrever o código em si. Então...

> Uma aplicação escrita proceduralmente gera um executável menor que a mesma aplicação escrita orientada a objeto?

A parte que cuida da estrutura de dados costuma sumir quando o código é compilado, essa parte só é usada para ajudar montar os algoritmos. É importante notar que o executável só costuma ter os algoritmos.

É possível usar metadados para dar mais riqueza de informação ao executável e facilitar atividades de reflexão, então usar um paradigma secundário reflexivo será mais responsável pelo executável crescer que a orientação a objeto que não precisa ser necessariamente gerador de código extra.

## Muita coisa determina o tamanho do executável

Outras formas de programar, arquitetura, e um série de influências vai determinar muito mais o tamanho do código.

Esse negócio de linguagem imperativa e linguagem orientada a objeto é outra coisa errada. Se são estilos de programação você pode usar um ou outro em qualquer linguagem, então essa forma de olhar para as linguagens é errada. Você [pode programar orientado a objeto em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101), então a comparação ficou mais difícil.

É ainda pior porque o tamanho do executável frequentemente é determinado pelo tamanho do *runtime* e biblioteca padrão da linguagem, além da forma como isto é usado. Por exemplo, C quase sempre não precisa de um grande uso no executável porque a biblioteca dela já está no sistema operacional e será carregado dinamicamente, então parece que ele é minúsculo e não é bem assim. Claro que a soma total ainda é pequena porque C é minimalista, mas isso nada tem a ver com paradigma. E embora não faça parte do executável o *runtime* está lá inteiro mesmo que você não use tudo dele, em código [*linkado* estaticamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149372/101) pode economizar por levar só o que precisa usar (mais ou menos), mas aí a comparação fica mais justa com linguagens que não podem contar com o *runtime* no sistema operacional e que tem algumas vantagens também.

## Comparando linguagens semelhantes

Então podemos comparar C com C++ que são linguagens muito próximas, algo até exclusivo de acontecer. C++ tem um executável sempre maior, mesmo que você faça uso 100% de procedural, e embora a diferença seja pequena, é maior até mesmo se fizer uso só de código C no compilador C++. Percebeu que tem outras coisas que influenciam? Mas se for observar o uso do mesmo código escrito procedural e orientado a objeto o segundo será **um pouco** maior, pelo menos pela minha experiência. Não digo que não seja possível ficar igual ou até o OO ficar menor em algumas circunstâncias, é que na prática a forma de programar se torna outra.

De fato ter mais métodos pequenos ajuda o código ficar maior. Mas se o compilador for bom ele linearizará a maioria deles (mas certamente não todos), e isto minimiza o problema.

Se usar uma forma polimórfica no procedural pode ocupar o mesmo ou mais espaço que em OO. Usar polimorfismo pode em alguns casos economizar espaço que um algoritmo que resolva em *runtime* alguma coisa que uma linguagem pode resolver em compilação (algumas não podem fazer isto), mas também tem polimorfismo que é resolvido em tempo de compilação e aumenta bem o tamanho código (mas isso é meta programação e não orientação a objeto).

Outras linguagens são mais difíceis de comparar porque elas possuem diversos outros compromissos, por isso termino como comecei, essa comparação feita de forma justa não faz sentido.

E o tamanho do executável é algo bem pouco importante.

Acho que ir além disto é fugir do foco e se precisa saber mais, agora tem subsídios para novas perguntas, até porque poderia virar um capítulo de um livro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).