# Qual a vantagem de se utilizar getters/setters em classes com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, getters-setters

Por exemplo neste código abaixo utilizo de métodos *getters* e *setters* na classe:

```js
class Pessoa {
  constructor(nome) {
    this.nomePessoa = nome;
  }
  get _nomes() {
    return this.nomePessoa;
  }
  set _nomes(valor) {
    this.nomePessoa = valor;
  }
}

const nomes = new Pessoa("Fulano");
console.log(nomes._nomes);                         // Fulano

nomes._nomes = "Ciclano";
console.log(nomes._nomes);                         // Ciclano
```

O programa retorna os dados corretamente, porém, posso obter os mesmos resultados com uma sintaxe muito mais simples:

```js
class Pessoa {
  constructor(nome) {
    this.nomePessoa = nome;
  }
  _nomes() {
    return this.nomePessoa;
  }
}

const nomes = new Pessoa("Fulano");
console.log(nomes._nomes());                       // Fulano

nomes._nomes = "Ciclano";
console.log(nomes._nomes);                         // Ciclano
```

- Qual seria o real emprego de métodos *getters*/*setters* em classes JavaScript?
- Há alguma vantagem em utilizá-los, se é que são necessários?

Comment: E como ficaria o *setter* no segundo exemplo?

Comment: `nomes._nome = "Ciclano"` eu não estou setando um novo valor?

Comment: LeAndrade, você está sobrescrevendo o método com uma string. O que acontecerá se você invocar `nomes._nomes()` depois de fazer `nomes._nomes = "Ciclano"`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Vantagens gerais

A vantagem é mais ou menos a mesma do uso em outras linguagens do ponto de vista conceitual, desde que seja necessário fazer algo relevante ali, o que não tem no exemplo.

O padrão de projeto *getter* e *setter* é uma forma de acessar um estado do objeto através de um método que pega o valor de um campo ou modificar o seu valor.

Se você faz isso pode executar algumas coisas em vez de simplesmente acessar o estado, então o *getter* pode não dar o valor bruto de um campo, mas sim algo calculado usando zero, um ou mais campos para obter o resultado, portanto ele nem precisa estar vinculado a um campo específico. Um *setter* pode manipular o valor recebido antes de gravar em um campo, ou pelo menos validar se o valor recebido está dentro do que se espera.

Em geral esse padrão é feito com métodos normais. Algumas linguagens provem uma sintaxe que faz com que estes métodos se confundam com o acesso ao campo, é o caso do JavaScript, e é disso que você está falando. Desta forma é possível fazer com que esses métodos se passem como se fossem campos (que [as pessoas chamam erroneamente de atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)), mas é um truque de sintaxe.

Algumas pessoas não gostam disto porque esconde alguma lógica que está por trás de algo que parece ser um simples acesso ou atribuição a uma variável. Mas se essa execução é detalhe de implementação então não importa, quem consome não deveria saber mesmo.

Uma vantagem que essas linguagens dão é que você pode começar usar o campo normalmente e depois mudar para um *getter* e *setter* sem mudar nada na sintaxe, então fica transparente uma mudança, você não precisa criar esse padrão antecipadamente.

Em outras linguagens pode ser útil já criar esse padrão de *getter/setter* mesmo que não vá usar porque se um dia precisa implementar alguma lógica já tem a sintaxe de método e não de campo. Em JS não precisa fazer isto porque a sintaxe do campo de do *getter/setter* é a mesma. Exemplo de linguagem que precisa é Java. Por isso Java pode se beneficiar mais de usar esses métodos mesmo que eles não façam nada, se um dia mudar, não precisa sair mudando os códigos consumidores.

Outras linguagens possuem sintaxe igual ao JS, mas elas possuem *binding*<sup>*</sup> antecipado, então mesmo que não precise de uma mudança de sintaxe se você passar de um campo para um *getter/setter* precisa recompilar o código todo de novo para ele fazer um novo *binding* e assim o código chamado se referenciar à nova forma agora com métodos transparentes sendo chamados para fazer o *get* e o *set*. Exemplo é C#. Se você muda um código consumidor de uma chamada ao campo para uma chamada ao método, tudo bem com a sintaxe, o problema é que se o código consumidor é compilado em ciclo diferente do código da sua classe que teve uma mudança de campo para método *getter/setter* (mesmo com sintaxe de campo como ocorre em C# ou JS), o código consumidor só saberá disso quando ele for recompilado olhando para a nova classe.

## "Vantagem" de usar *getter/setter* que acrescenta nada

Em JS não existe compilação, o *binding* é feito na execução, então nem isso é problema para ela. Se está perguntando se deveria usar *getter/setter* todas as vezes mesmo que não tenha lógica alguma, então, não, em JS não tem vantagem. A vantagem se dá no momento que tenha alguma lógica no *acessador* ou modificador, portanto, algum algoritmo executando seja no *getter*, seja no *setter*.

Use a sintaxe simples até precisar de algo mais complicado.

Mas claro, se um dia achar uma implementação de JS compilada, tem que pensar. Sua classe será consumida por sua equipe e poderá garantir que o código consumidor dela sempre será recompilado se a classe mudar também vai bem, mas se for usada por terceiros, se você não puder controlar quando o código consumidor for recompilado, aí você pode estar em problemas. Mas não vamos dar certeza, vai depender de como isso for implementado nesta hipotética implementação de JavaSrript.

Algumas pessoas usam o *getter/setter* mesmo sem precisar porque leram em algum lugar que é pra fazer assim e como elas não aprenderam a programar mas sim a seguir receitas de bolo que não entendem elas fazem coisas sem sentido e prejudicam seu próprio código. Algumas pessoas só fazem porque a equipe é gerenciada por alguém assim que obriga fazer isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

---

<sup>*</sup>O momento que o código real é efetivamente vinculado à chamada. Em linguagens compiladas costuma ser o momento da compilação (em alguns casos pode ser no momento do [*linking*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101) (em alguns casos [momento da carga](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149372/101)) ou até do [JITer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) do código, mas não assuma nada, cada implementação é de um jeito. Em linguagens interpretadas, a não ser que tenha alguma otimização ou algo na especificação que diga algo diferente, o vínculo é sempre no momento que vai executar, então qualquer mudança em uma parte do que está sendo executado para rodar a aplicação já é percebido pela aplicação toda, a não ser que use algum truque específico.

Comment: Perfeito man, mas, uma vez bastante esclarecedor.

Comment: O negativo deve ter sido dado porque alguém que aprendeu que a receita de bolo deve ser seguida sempre.

Comment: Muito provavelmente :)

Answer (score 7):

É mais uma questão de opinião. Creio que a corrente mais comum de opinião desencoraja o uso de tal forma de declaração, alguns motivos incluem:

- Legibilidade de código, código não-explícito (um acesso a uma propriedade está na verdade chamando uma função);
- É mais complicado de sobrescrever a função (você terá que usar um dos métodos base de objeto do javascript);
- Otimizações de empacotadores. Empacotadores de código javascript (webpack, rollup) usam lógicas pra determinar se uma seção de código é ou não usada e removê-la da compilação final. O uso de getters e setters pode evitar a marcação de uma seção de código pra remoção (o bundler não tem como saber se aquele código é acessado por poder gerar "side-effects").

Você pode ver o uso frequente desses recursos na própria API DOM, por exemplo, ao escrever `window.location.href = 'xxx'` você está na verdade invocando um setter. Pode ser até útil em casos de refactor mas realmente fica mais a seu critério e do problema que você precisa solucionar.

Comment: Boa explanação, realmente é de se pensar o uso. Obrigado por responder.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro: Qual o motivo de usar os Getters and Setters?

Eles são utilizados se outros objetos precisam de acesso aos atributos, o objeto
fornece operações públicas (conhecidas como getters e setters) para manipular esses atributos. Ou seja, uma forma de acessa seus atributos em uma classe que é privada e está encapsulada.

Getters é conhecido como Acessor e Setters como Mutator, ambos estão na padronização do ECMAScript. Exemplo de uso: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp

Então não é a questão de ser algo apenas relevante, é como se pega valores dos atributos em POO seguindo a padronização.

Qual a vantagem? - talvez alguns já façam isso e nem sabe que está utilizando Acessors ou Mutator, que nada mais é que pegar valores e atribuir valores de uma classe como já explicado, porém, de forma encapsulada.

É a prática da POO, em acessar as variáveis de um objeto, não é questão de vantagem, ou ser um super projeto, é nada mais que a maneira correta de se fazer. Como já citei, está no padrão estabelecido pelo JavaScript e quem procurar vai ver que é um padrão de POO.

Independente da linguagem é esse o conceito e o motivo de ser utilizado, agora como vai ser utilizado cada linguagem tem a maneira correta de se fazer.

```
Exemplo: getter
     
// Create an object:

var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "en",
  get lang() {
    return this.language;
  }
};

// Display data from the object using a getter:
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.lang;


Exemplo: setters

  var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "",
  set lang(lang) {
    this.language = lang;
  }
};

// Set an object property using a setter:
person.lang = "en";

// Display data from the object:
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.language;
```