# Por que usamos um "get" antes de declarar uma função no Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

- Por que usamos um `get` antes de declarar uma função no Angular ou do JavaScript?
- Isso é uma prática do Angular?

```
get funcaoExemplo() {
    return this.exemplo.length === (this.exemplo2 + 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isto nada tem a ver com Angular, este pode por acaso usar isto, tem a ver com JavaScript. Este método usa um padrão de projeto chamado *getter* (tem o *setter* também). Em algumas linguagens este padrão é adotado pelo programador e só ele sabe que aquele método tem essa finalidade. Em JS, assim como outras linguagens, possui sintaxe própria para isto e assim dá uma semântica melhor indicando para o compilador que o método é um *getter*.

Mas não para aí, ele permite que a sintaxe de chamada de método funcione como se fosse um campo do objeto, então esse *getter* funciona como uma propriedade mesmo.

O nome do exemplo é péssimo e falta contexto, mas poderia fazer assim:

```
console.log(objeto.funcaoExemplo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/PassFunction.js).

Resultaria em `true` ou `false`.

Pode ver mais em [Qual a vantagem de se utilizar getters/setters em classes com JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/416974/101).

Obviamente que funciona em TypeScript também.

Answer (score 6):

> Por que usamos um get antes de declarar uma função no Angular ou do
>   Javascript?

Usamos para associar a propriedade de um objeto a uma função. A função é chamada quando a propriedade é acessada.

> Isso é uma prática do Angular?

Não, isso é do JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

**Exemplo:**

```
get funcaoExemplo() {
    return this.exemplo.length === (this.exemplo2 + 1);
}
```

Acesso

```
console.log(obj.funcaoExemplo);
```